# Acronyms sorted alphabetically in Index

Tags: indexing, acronyms

I am using glossaries package with the acronym option `\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}`. When my Index is generated, the acronyms are not listed alphabetically but rather as a "Symbol" entry within the index (image below). I am writing a thesis and have a separate list of Acronyms so this "Symbol" entry in the Index is rather useless for me. Is there a way that the acronyms can be sorted alphabetically in the Index just like the rest of the entries?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\makeindex
\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{cd}{CD}{compact disk}


\begin{document}
\noindent
First\index{first} use of \gls{cd}\\
subsequent\index{subsequent} use of \gls{cd}\index{\glsfirst{cd}}

\printglossaries
\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image: Index]

Comment: Just don't use the `\index` after running `\gls`. You should get a `Acronyms` chapter with all your `\gls` entries and an `Index` chapter with "fist" and "subsequent. Is that what you want?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the last sentence, that you want to have it in both lists. You may try `\index{compact@\glsfirst{cd}}`. Haven't tried it. Maybe with space after `@` or curly brackets around the `\glsfirst{cd}`. Give it a try.

Comment: @larifari As a mather of fact, besides from the answer given, I indeed found an alternate solution using sorting by @, adding the following:`\let\oldgls\gls
\renewcommand*{\gls}[1]{\oldgls{#1}\index{#1@\glsfirst{#1}}}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The argument of `\index` doesn't get expanded when written to the `.idx` file, so `makeindex` is trying to sort `\glsfirst{cd}`. Since `makeindex` doesn't interpret TeX commands, it views this as a string starting with the backslash character, which is why the entry is considered a symbol. Here's a way of automatically indexing subsequent uses of the acronyms that expands the indexed term before writing it to the `.idx` file:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*{\CustomAcronymFields}{%
  name={\the\glsshorttok},%
  symbol={\the\glsshorttok},%
  text={\the\glsshorttok\protect\index{\the\glslongtok\space(\the\glsshorttok)}},%
  plural={\the\glsshorttok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix\protect\index{\the\glslongtok\space(\the\glsshorttok)}},%
  first={\the\glslongtok\space(\the\glsshorttok)},%
  firstplural={\the\glslongtok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix\space(\the\glsshorttok)},%
  description={\the\glslongtok}%
}

\SetCustomStyle

\newacronym{cd}{CD}{compact disk}


\begin{document}
\noindent
First\index{first} use of \gls{cd}\\
subsequent\index{subsequent} use of \gls{cd}.

\printglossaries
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Assuming I have the `makeindex` headings flag set (via `headings_flag 1`
 in a `.ist` file) I get the following index:

[image: Image of index page]

If you only want to index some subsequent entries rather than all of them, here's another approach that saves the index command with expanded argument in the `user1` field:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*{\CustomAcronymFields}{%
  name={\the\glsshorttok},%
  symbol={\the\glsshorttok},%
  text={\the\glsshorttok},%
  plural={\the\glsshorttok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix},%
  first={\the\glslongtok\space(\the\glsshorttok)},%
  firstplural={\the\glslongtok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix\space(\the\glsshorttok)},%
  description={\the\glslongtok},%
  user1={\protect\index{\the\glslongtok\space(\the\glsshorttok)}}%
}

\SetCustomStyle

\newacronym{cd}{CD}{compact disk}


\begin{document}
\noindent
First\index{first} use of \gls{cd}\\
subsequent\index{subsequent} use of \gls{cd}.

\newpage

Another use of \gls{cd}\glsuseri{cd}.

\printglossaries
\printindex

\end{document}
```

The index now looks like:

[image: Image of index]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I found another solution redefining the \gls{} command: `\let\oldgls\gls
\renewcommand*{\gls}[1]{\oldgls{#1}\index{#1@\glsfirst{#1}}}`. As I understand, it asks to sort each entry as stated itself by \gls{}.

Comment: I have a question: the acronyms are only displayed when used twice, any ideas on how to modify the code so all of them are listed, even if `\gls{}` is only mentioned once? I posted a question here: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130322/acronyms-only-shown-in-index-when-used-twice]