# Formated text in acronym sorted alphabetically in Index

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, sorting

I am using glossaries package with the acronym option `\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}`.

An answer provided previously ([Acronyms only shown in Index when used twice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130322/acronyms-only-shown-in-index-when-used-twice])) works perfectly for listing acronyms in the Index with the instruction `\gls{some_acronym}`

Working on a new long thesis document I noticed that when an acronym text is formatted such as: 
`\newacronym{ita}{ITA}{\emph{italic text} acronym}` 
the acronym is listed in the Index under a "**Symbols**" category:

[image: output of code]

I would like to have formatted acronyms listed in the Index in alphabetical order. Any ideas?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*{\CustomAcronymFields}{%
  name={\the\glsshorttok},%
  symbol={\the\glsshorttok},%
  text={\the\glsshorttok\protect\index{\the\glslongtok\space(\the\glsshorttok)}},%
  plural={\the\glsshorttok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix\protect\index{\the\glslongtok\space(\the\glsshorttok)}},%
  first={\the\glslongtok\space(\the\glsshorttok)\protect\index{\the\glslongtok\space(\the\glsshorttok)}},%
  firstplural={\the\glslongtok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix\space(\the\glsshorttok)\protect\index{\the\glslongtok\space(\the\glsshorttok)}},%
  description={\the\glslongtok}%
}

\SetCustomStyle

\newacronym{cd}{CD}{compact disk}
\newacronym{un}{UN}{United Nations}
\newacronym{ita}{ITA}{\emph{italic text} acronym}
\newacronym{mc}{MC}{4-methyl-compound}
\newacronym{hgh}{HGH}{human growth hormone}
\newacronym{pi}{pI}{isoelectric point}


\begin{document}
\noindent
First\index{first} use of \gls{cd}\\
subsequent\index{subsequent} use of \gls{cd}
, and
\gls{un} and
\gls{ita} and
\gls{mc} and
\gls{hgh} and again \gls{hgh} and
\gls{pi}.

\printglossaries
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `makeindex` doesn't understand (La)TeX commands. The `.idx` file created by your MWE contains:

```
\indexentry{first}{1}
\indexentry{compact disk (CD)}{1}
\indexentry{subsequent}{1}
\indexentry{compact disk (CD)}{1}
\indexentry{United Nations (UN)}{1}
\indexentry{\emph  {italic text} acronym (ITA)}{1}
\indexentry{4-methyl-compound (MC)}{1}
\indexentry{human growth hormone (HGH)}{1}
\indexentry{human growth hormone (HGH)}{1}
\indexentry{isoelectric point (pI)}{1}
```

`makeindex` interprets `\emph  {italic text} acronym (ITA)` as a string of characters `\`, `e`, `m`, `p`, `h`, etc. The first character is a backslash so `makeindex` puts it in the "Symbols" group. There are two options: provide `makeindex` with a different sort key that doesn't contain any formatting commands or use `xindy` instead (which simply ignores any LaTeX commands found in the sort key).

If you want to stick with `makeindex`, it's possible to modify your definition of `\CustomAcronymFields` so that it uses the same sort key that the glossary entry uses. The modified definition is:

```
\renewcommand*{\CustomAcronymFields}{%
  name={\the\glsshorttok},%
  symbol={\the\glsshorttok},%
  text={\the\glsshorttok\protect\index{\noexpand\glsentrysort{\the\glslabeltok}@\the\glslongtok\space(\the\glsshorttok)}},%
  plural={\the\glsshorttok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix\protect\index{\noexpand\glsentrysort{\the\glslabeltok}@\the\glslongtok\space(\the\glsshorttok)}},%
  first={\the\glslongtok\space(\the\glsshorttok)\protect\index{\noexpand\glsentrysort{\the\glslabeltok}@\the\glslongtok\space(\the\glsshorttok)}},%
  firstplural={\the\glslongtok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix\space(\the\glsshorttok)\protect\index{\noexpand\glsentrysort{\the\glslabeltok}@\the\glslongtok\space(\the\glsshorttok)}},%
  description={\the\glslongtok}%
}
```

This now creates the following `.idx` file:

```
\indexentry{first}{1}
\indexentry{CD@compact disk (CD)}{1}
\indexentry{subsequent}{1}
\indexentry{CD@compact disk (CD)}{1}
\indexentry{UN@United Nations (UN)}{1}
\indexentry{ITA@\emph  {italic text} acronym (ITA)}{1}
\indexentry{MC@4-methyl-compound (MC)}{1}
\indexentry{HGH@human growth hormone (HGH)}{1}
\indexentry{HGH@human growth hormone (HGH)}{1}
\indexentry{pI@isoelectric point (pI)}{1}
```

(The sort key is the bit before the `@` character in each entry.) This now sorts according to the acronym rather than the full form. You can neaten things up a bit and reduce the chances of error by doing:

```
\newcommand*{\gindex}{%
  \protect\index{\noexpand\glsentrysort{\the\glslabeltok}@\the\glslongtok\space
    (\the\glsshorttok)}%
}

\renewcommand*{\CustomAcronymFields}{%
  name={\the\glsshorttok},%
  symbol={\the\glsshorttok},%
  text={\the\glsshorttok\gindex},%
  plural={\the\glsshorttok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix\gindex},%
  first={\the\glslongtok\space(\the\glsshorttok)\gindex},%
  firstplural={\the\glslongtok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix\space(\the\glsshorttok)\gindex},%
  description={\the\glslongtok}%
}
```

However, it would be better to sort on the long form, so if you still want to stick with `makeindex`, the following modification will strip `\emph` from the entry:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\newacronymhook}{%
  {%
    \let\emph\@firstofone
    \expandafter\protected@xdef\expandafter\gindexsort
       \expandafter{\the\glslongtok}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\gindex}{%
  \protect\index{\gindexsort @\the\glslongtok\space (\the\glsshorttok)}%
}
```

If you have other formatting commands, for example `\textbf`, they can be stripped in the same way:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\newacronymhook}{%
  {%
    \let\emph\@firstofone
    \let\textbf\@firstofone
    \expandafter\protected@xdef\expandafter\gindexsort
       \expandafter{\the\glslongtok}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

The `.idx` file now contains:

```
\indexentry{first}{1}
\indexentry{compact disk@compact disk (CD)}{1}
\indexentry{subsequent}{1}
\indexentry{compact disk@compact disk (CD)}{1}
\indexentry{United Nations@United Nations (UN)}{1}
\indexentry{italic text acronym@\emph  {italic text} acronym (ITA)}{1}
\indexentry{4-methyl-compound@4-methyl-compound (MC)}{1}
\indexentry{human growth hormone@human growth hormone (HGH)}{1}
\indexentry{human growth hormone@human growth hormone (HGH)}{1}
\indexentry{isoelectric point@isoelectric point (pI)}{1}
```

The resulting index now looks like:

[image: Image of sorted index]

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to have been fixed by now. When compiling the MWE on Overleaf, it turns out fine.

However, there is a highly related issue and that is when the acronym (not the long form) starts with "\".

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{cd}{CD}{compact disk}
\newacronym{un}{UN}{United Nations}
\newacronym{ita}{\emph{ITA}}{italic text acronym} % \emph is in the acronym, not the long form
\newacronym{mc}{MC}{4-methyl-compound}
\newacronym{hgh}{HGH}{human growth hormone}
\newacronym{pi}{pI}{isoelectric point}


\begin{document}
\noindent
First\index{first} use of \gls{cd}\\
subsequent\index{subsequent} use of \gls{cd}
, and
\gls{un} and
\gls{ita} and
\gls{mc} and
\gls{hgh} and again \gls{hgh} and
\gls{pi}.

\printglossaries
\printindex

\end{document}
```

You can fix this very easily by using the optional `sort` argument of `newacronym` as pointed out [here](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=14795).

```
\newacronym[sort=italic text]{ita}{\emph{ITA}}{italic text acronym}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use the `makeidx`-package? Don't exactly know whats the problem with it, but without it works fine, even without your indexes. But thats a build-in function of glossaries too, you can use the package option `index` with the according commands described in section 2.6 of the glossaries user manual.

Heres your modified MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%\usepackage{makeidx}
%\makeindex
\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts,index]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*{\CustomAcronymFields}{%
  name={\the\glsshorttok},%
  symbol={\the\glsshorttok},%
  text={\the\glsshorttok\protect\index{\the\glslongtok\space(\the\glsshorttok)}},%
  plural={\the\glsshorttok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix\protect\index{\the\glslongtok\space(\the\glsshorttok)}},%
  first={\the\glslongtok\space(\the\glsshorttok)\protect\index{\the\glslongtok\space(\the\glsshorttok)}},%
  firstplural={\the\glslongtok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix\space(\the\glsshorttok)\protect\index{\the\glslongtok\space(\the\glsshorttok)}},%
  description={\the\glslongtok}%
}

\SetCustomStyle

\newacronym{cd}{CD}{compact disk}
\newacronym{un}{UN}{United Nations}
\newacronym{ita}{ITA}{\emph{italic text} acronym}
\newacronym{mc}{MC}{4-methyl-compound}
\newacronym{hgh}{HGH}{human growth hormone}
\newacronym{pi}{pI}{isoelectric point}
\newterm{first}
\newterm{subsequent}

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \Gls{first} use of \gls{cd}\\
  \gls{subsequent} use of \gls{cd}
  , and
  \gls{un} and
  \gls{ita} and
  \gls{mc} and
  \gls{hgh} and again \gls{hgh} and
  \gls{pi}.

  \printglossaries
%  \printindex

\end{document}
```

For me, it produces that output:

[image: Output of MWE]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Perhaps a screen shot of the output would help

Comment: Thank you. The Acronym list output is not an issue at all, actually I get the Acronym list just like you. However my desire is to get all the acronyms in the index so it is shown where they are used throughout the document. The MWE I provided (from that previous answer) does just that, except that I hand't the need before for formatted acronyms and that is why I have just noticed they are listed inside the Index as "Symbols". My document is more than 150 pages long and a solution using `{glossaries}` would be much appreciated.

Comment: First idea (but not the finest one indeed) would be to define your indexes as acronyms with empty long form `\newacronym{first}{first}{}` and rename your "Acronym"-list to "Index". But there will be better suggestions I think...